# Can makefiles be used to insert code?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

This is a homework assignment. I have a makefile that by default compiles an executable using 
`gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c`

In the assignment we are supposed to make 3 extra make cases: "The makefile should also support inserting a sleep of 10 seconds into 3 different specified places of the program using these 3 cases`make test1`, `make test2`, `make test3`.

I know how to use make to have extra cases like this from the default, but my question is can makefiles be used to insert code into myprogram.c before compiling the executable? Or would i have to create myprogram1.c myprogram2.c etc and then use those for the cases?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution would be a macro that you can define at compile time, like

```
int main(void)
{
    SLEEP_HERE;
    return 0;
}
```

and at compile time

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -DSLEEP_HERE='sleep(10)' -o myprogram myprogram.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not create three separate files.

Create a macro inside your file

```
#ifndef DELAY_SEC
#define DELAY_SEC 0
#endif
```

Now use the macro DELAY_SEC everywhere and it will have the value 0 if compiled normally.

Now in the Makefile for the target where you want delay of 10 seconds compile as

```
gcc -DDELAY_SEC=10 -o myprogram myprogram.c
```

And so on for other delays and it should compile accordingly.